# Selenium Element Click not Working after Zoom In while using Chrome

Tags: selenium, zooming

Need help in automating my use case using selenium

My Usecase to automate

1. Navigate to a page
2. Zoom Out page (  I am aware of the fact 100% is accurate for selenium scripts, but I have to make the page to 90% )
3. Click on Save button in the page
4. Reset zoom level of the page

I tried the following two approaches

**Approach#1** : ( With this there is no change in zoom setting and script failed )

```
mysavelement.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT));
mysavelement.click();
mysavelement.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "0"));
```

**Approach#2** : ( With this approach zoom setting got changed and script passed. Though script passed, click functionality is not working means save not happening )

```
 Robot robot = new Robot();
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT);
 mysavelement.click();
```

Comment: could you also mention how you have located webelement mysavelement ?

Comment: Hi, did your problem got solved? If yes, could you please mention the resolution?

Comment: Nope, looks like this is an open issue with chromedriver. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=628

Answer (score 3):

I too have experienced click functionality sometimes failing on chrome browser when I try to zoom-in/out the browser. But, for firefox, it works fine. I don't know the reason for such a behavior, but javascript click workaround helped in such scenarios. Try, below work-around if not already tried:

> (JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",
>   mysavelement);